# Summation To Infinity Question

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]How would I go about finding the sum of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use partial fractions to split the terms into a telescopic series.
Terms will get cancelled out and you will remain with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac2{r^2-1}=\frac{r+1-(r-1)}{(r+1)(r-1)}=\cdots$$

Set a few initial values of $n$ to identify the [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)